# Modify deeply nested data in Apollo client query result

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, storyblok

I'm using `@apollo/client` to fetch data from [Storyblok's](https://www.storyblok.com/) API.

I want to iterate over all the fields in the returned data to potentially sanitize its content (it contains raw HTML). Because Apollo makes the result data immutable, I'm not able to do this:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://gapi.storyblok.com/v1/api",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    token: "EXAMPLE",
  },
});

function sanitizeFields(obj) {
  for (const field of obj) {
    if (field?.type === "custom-rich-text") {
      field.content = sanitizeContent(field.content); //  This generates an error because I'm trying to modify a read only object
    }

    if (Array.isArray(field) || isPlainObject(field)) {
      sanitizeFields(field);
    }
  }
}

const postData = await client.query({ query: MY_QUERY });

sanitizeFields(postData?.data?.Page);
```

How can I modify deeply nested data returned by `@apollo/client` without knowing the particular field name beforehand?

Comment: data should be sanitized on write (API), not read ... do it on editor component (read+invalidate on init?) ... immutable handle immutable way (deep clone)? ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/ ?

Comment: It's not uncommon to escape values before rendering them to HTML to prevent XSS attacks. In my case, I need to do it in this way as opposed to just calling the sanitize function directly in my view.

Comment: The `read` function seems very promising, but from what I can tell, I can only use that when I know the field name in advance?

Comment: in graphql you know field names ... json scalars? ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#combining-reads-and-writes - immutable modify cache example